# Ubuntu 18.04 alongside 16.04 on same partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a hybrid disk drive with two partitions on it - one for windows and other for Ubuntu. I had Ubuntu 16.04 before, but since then it won't boot anymore(also won't upgrade to newer version), so I decided to install a newer 18.04.Installer gave me options to erase or install 18.04 alongside 16.04, but when I choose second option it warns me:

> If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually
>
> The partition tables of the following devices are changed:
>   SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)
>
> The following partitions are going to be formatted:
>   partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) as ESP
>   partition #6 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) as ext4

This message goes about /dev/sda completely and not sda2, where Ubuntu is installed. Will it interfere /dev/sda1 where windows is installed? Or corrupt Ubuntu 16.04 because of formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is creating new partitions #5 and #6. Information about it must be written to partition table on /dev/sda.

It is not going to change sda2 or sda1.